# Change "Add to cart" button color in Magento

Tags: css, magento

I am using Magento 1.8 with "modern" built-in template and want to change the color of the "Add to cart" button and the text color too.

Comment: can you tell what class applied to `add to cart` button?

Comment: class="button btn-cart"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want  to change the style of Add to Cart button please change the following CSS code witht this one.

```
.btn-cart{background-color:red; color:green;}

<input type="button" value=" " class="btn-cart" />
```

you can change the `font color` and `background color` as per your theme.

Comment: I have several files in several places, but I don't know which file to edit

Comment: As you said you are using "modern" Magento theme. so you can find the CSS file inside this theme folder and then search for `.btn-cart` class and put the above code  and rest line of code can be commented.

Comment: If the given solution works for you. then close this by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the theme's folder and edit the css file.

***Hint***: use the inspect tool your browser offers in order to find the element that needs changing.

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2, you have to add this CSS rule

```
button.tocart {
  background-color:red !important;
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```